# Simple PHP Delete All Files Except the 3 last days -

Tags: php, ftp

There is a FTP user and a DIR : /home/user/public_html/**backups**/

Everyday on 03:00 a folder with date and in that folder a file of **3,5GB** will be added automatically there trough FTP.
Now if there will be added **3,5GB** everyday in the map **backups** that will be **49GB** in 14 days.

And about 14 days i will be have this Folder structure:

```
2015-12-18
2015-12-17
2015-12-16
2015-12-15
2015-12-14
2015-12-13
2015-12-13
2015-12-12
2015-12-11
2015-12-10
2015-12-09
2015-12-08
```

So i was thinking to make a cronjob script for this, that every sunday night on 00:00u a **.php** will be excuted automatically with a cronjob.

Example on: `2015-12-18` a .php script will be executed, and that all folders will deleted except the last 3 added folders: `2015-12-18 - 2015-12-17 - 2015-12-16`

The .php script will delete all files **EXPECT** the last 3 added folders/files 
in the map **Backups**

Is this posibble with .PHP? So yes, does someone have a sample script for me?
Or can it be done with a better solution?

Comment: what OS, you don't need php for this

Comment: CentOS, but i also want to know it if is also possible with .PHP because there is a "sever" and i don't have SSH access on that one. @Dagon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is it. 
You populate an array of all directories using glob, you slice the array to remove the last 3 items, and you delete the others.

```
$files = glob('/tmp/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

$deletions = array_slice($files, 0, count($files) - 3);

foreach($deletions as $to_delete) {
    array_map('unlink', glob("$to_delete/*.*"));
    $deleted = rmdir($to_delete);
}
```

Comment: I just edited my answer, it was checking for 3 hours instead of 3 days.

Comment: I have executed your php script but if i refresh here, is still see this: http://i.imgur.com/IQKSoXS.png

Comment: edited my answer with some debug information :)
also check that PHP can unlink the files (+w for your php user on that directory)

Comment: is your $files array populated with the file names ?
is the debug foreach showing anything ?

Comment: The folder names are automaticlly dates.. So , read good my question, i think you are mistaking.. I need to delete FOLDERS so example  /var/www/html/backup.php - That has to delete all FOLDERS in the map : /var/ww/html/backups/ except the last 3 days folders... So this is 'a' structure of /backups/ : http://i.imgur.com/IQKSoXS.png

Comment: ok, edited my answer. you can pass a param to glob for it to retrieve directories only, and rmdir instead of unlink.

Comment: @ Di Dier , Thanks! I tried it.. i apprecatie your help, but that script has deleted all folders in the map /backups/ hahaha, the last 3 day's dont stayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98508/discussion-between-didier-sampaolo-and-dombre).

Comment: Thanks for this answer @DidierSampaolo

Answer (score 0):

nix*, no php required, you can run this as the cronjob

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: @Dragon Thanks! I tried it with CENTOS in the Terminal : http://i.imgur.com/mL1Jmby.png but the folders are stil there: http://i.imgur.com/ys9vDDf.png

Comment: they are not older than 3 days based on the time stamp shown

Comment: Yes because i am testing it now before i put the script on for real work.. Actually he has to delete all folders EXCEPT the last 3 added folders..

Answer (score -2):

I am not very familiar with a time on PHP haven't play for too much but  I will do something like this :

if today is sunday will set todays date to a database as a date that was last time deleted , then make some simple code witch checks how many days passed or seconds or what ever and if passed like a 7 days will delete everything from a database except last try days added items that's kind a simple I think `

Comment: If you are not familiar then don't answer this question, because there is never "database" written, but thank you for you explain, but this answer doens't help me

Comment: i know its the same thing i just give a example cuz i am always using a database u can do it without

Comment: this is a comment (at best) not an answer